# MP4 files are not played in IE9

Tags: asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-9, mp4, mime

In my asp.net web application there are couple of videos as link.

```
<a href="test.mp4" target="_blank">
```

On clicking each link, browser will open the `MP4` video in `Windows Media Player`.

But on some machines alone in `IE9`, it is returning codec error. Whereas the same video is opening in the same machine in `chrome` browser.

[image: Codec Error]

1. MIME type is mapped in IIS
2. All neccessary codecs for playing MP4 files are already installed.

What could be the issue?

**Update after 1st Answer:**

It is reproducing only in some IE9 in some machines. Many machines it is working fined with IE9

Comment: Did you ever finish resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things. You need the meta tag to set the mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

<video width="400" height="300" preload controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag
</video>
```

you could also try using the videojs plugin, for all browser support.

I have also seen, IE9 specific, that you can encode with compression H.264.

Try one of those things, and hopefully it will work :)

UPDATE: Can you use a video tag instead of a hyperlink? Is it a requirement that it opens in Media Player and NOT in the browser?

Comment: `IE9 specific, that you can encode with compression H.264`. Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: But this is reproducing only in some machines with IE9. It is working fine in IE9 in different machines.

Comment: I am not using any video tags. It will be a simple link. Please read the question once again

Comment: Are you sure that it is the same version of IE9 on every machine?
Can you play them directly on the PC with Media Player / Winamp etc. where they do not load via IE9?

Comment: Working Version WMP - 12.0.7601.18741. Not working Version WMP - Version 12.0.7601.17514

Comment: Yes Requirements can't be changed

Comment: I can see some version difference in codecs. video Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder msmpeg2vdec.dll 6.1.7140.0. Working version has 12.0.9200.16426. Does it helps?

Comment: One way to find out - use the newer codec instead. If it works, that will be the solution I'd say.

Comment: Wher can i download new codec and add it to windows media player?

Comment: Microsoft's site will have the information. Otherwise, Google is your friend :)